# HTML5 FS API: Let the user create files outside of the sandbox?

Tags: javascript, filesystems

Is there a way to create a file outside of the sandbox? Maybe something that works by first storing the file inside the sandbox and then letting the user drag a link to the locally stored file into a regular folder?

It is for a webchat: I want the user to be able to receive files, but I can't figure out a way that ensures that he can choose the target location that doesn't need a right-click->save as. If there is a better solution than using the filesystem API, feel free to suggest that, too.

Comment: Storing the file on the server and providing a download link is not an option?

Comment: @Eliasdx: How would I force a "select destination folder" or "save as" or whatever dialog?

Comment: @thejh: That's not possible with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an "a" element with [a download attribute](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download), and using [FileEntry.toURL()](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/#widl-Entry-toURL-DOMString) to populate the href target?

Answer (score 0):

Use a signed java applet to get root access to the system